# How do I unit test REST methods in App Engine?

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-datastore

I haven't found a way to test REST methods for my application automatically, while using setUp and tearDown methods to preserve the uniqueness of each test.

[gaetestbed](https://github.com/jgeewax/gaetestbed/) gives me a clean datastore in between tests. And [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) allows me to easily call REST methods and parse their responses; but in order to do so, a local instance of my application must be running on port 8080 and called each test. This defeats the purpose of a gaetestbed-like refresh of the datastore, since data is preserved in between calls.

I could start and stop the GAE server within the **setUp** and **tearDown** methods, but this seems wasteful and time-consuming. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using gaetestbed, or your own unittest code like [this](https://gist.github.com/186251), simply instantiate your handler classes directly, using a mocked/fake environment dictionary, and call the methods (initialize() and get()/post()/etc in the case of webapp) directly.

Answer (score 0):

When doing functional tests using REST methods we ended up writing helper calls to clean out the internal caches and force our engine to sync with the database.

I haven't used gaetestbed, but I would have thought that you could [flush the datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/gae_backup_and_restore.html) between tests?

```
"Use case: develop and test locally with real data
Restore to: your local development server.
Once you have restored the data to your local development server, I would highly suggest that you take a backup of your datastore.
You can find your datastore files in a temporary folder on your local machine (e.g., on my Mac, it's /var/folders/bz/bzDU030xHXK-jKYLMXnTzk+++TI/-Tmp-/). To find the folder on your own machine, flush the datastore (./manage.py flush) and you will see the path to your datastore folder printed in the resulting output."
```